# Multiple groups in one regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match two groups in the same Regex object in .NET, so I can process them separately; I'd hate to instantiate many objects for every individual expression. Basically, I'd like to insert an underscore before a period and a dash before an exclamation point. Now, I know I can use punctuation constructs, but I'd like to use each group as an individual expression.

Here's a variation of the million ways I've tried:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public Form1()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            var rule = new Regex(@"(\.)(\!)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var myText = "string. will! way. water! test. quiz! short. long!";
            richTextBox1.Text = rule.Replace(rule.Replace(myText, "_$1"), "-$2");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: My favorite [Replace(string,string, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may provide more readable code for your case... Otherwise check [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and read about replacement patterns like `$1`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work. It uses a Lamba, but if you want more control you can break it out into a function. The Match delegate can be either. Basically the regex engine calls your delegate with each match, passing in the matched value, so you can decide what to do with it on the fly.

```
Regex.Replace("Test a. b!", @"([.!])",
       (m) => { return m.Value == "." ? "_." : "-!"; }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28VS.71%29.aspx) rewriting your code as follows:

Instead of multiple capturing groups you can use a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to include both characters.

```
string s = "string. will! way. water! test. quiz! short. long!";
string r = Regex.Replace(s, @"[!.]", delegate(Match m) {
         return m.Value == "!" ? "-!" : "_.";
});

//=> "string_. will-! way_. water-! test_. quiz-! short_. long-!"
```

As far as multiple groups .NET doesn't support the branch reset feature `(?| ... | ... )`, but one way you could do this would be named groups, you can reuse them without restriction.

```
string r = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?:(?<punc>\.)|(?<punc>!))", delegate(Match m) {
         return m.Groups["punc"].Value == "!" ? "-!" : "_.";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is: **You can't use groups to do that.** Multiple replacement 
strings just aren't supported, and neither is putting the replacement string into the match itself.

You can use a regex and a match evaluator to do what you want, as the other answers show, but groups play no part in that.

The solution to your problem is: **Use plain string replacements.** You're not doing anything complicated enough to require a regex.

```
var myText = "string. will! way. water! test. quiz! short. long!";
richTextBox1.Text = myText.Replace(".", "_.").Replace("!", "-!");
```

Comment: Oh, I understand; I just used the punctuation marks example to see if it was possible to do such a thing with other complex groups. Heck if I could avoid regexes all together, I would.

Comment: If you have complex regexes, then you should still use two separate replacements, even if string.Replace isn't sufficient.

Comment: +1. For simple replace option. Side note: "Multiple replacement strings just aren't supported"? I'm not exactly sure what you mean... you may consider if some other way of saying what you want could be more clear.